# Remove files created between certain time stamps. 

Tags: linux, time, sorting, debian, rm

Last night I had a script go a bit crazy and create a bunch of directories between 3:00 and 3:09am. Is there a quick one liner that will hunt these down and remove them for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can search for the first and last (chronological) directories you want to delete, then you can use find:

```
find . -newer first -not -newer last -type d
```

And if the output suits you, go for the delete

```
find . -newer first -not -newer last -type d -print0 |  xargs -0 rmdir
```

or with explicit date stamps:

```
find . -newermt "2010-03-31 0300" -not -newermt "2010-03-31 0310" -type d
```

Comment: Running this gives the flag 

xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, if you are working in just one directory and the 5th field of the `ls -ltrog` output is the time.

```
ls -ltrog | awk '$5~/03:0[0-9]/{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5="";gsub("^ +",""); cmd="rm \047"$0"\047";system(cmd) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use **find**

```
find . -type d -newermt "2010-03-31 0300" -and \( -not -newermt "2010-03-31 0310" \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: This wil delete the directories with all their content, not the files only.